# How to set indentation within grammar environment?

Tags: indentation, syntax

I'm using `mdwtools` and `syntax` package to write BNF grammar, I wonder is there a way to set the `parindent` so that each production line will be center algined instead of left aligned by default?

**Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}  
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{syntax} 

\setlength{\grammarparsep}{0.25cm}   % vertical distance between production rules
\setlength{\grammarindent}{1cm}      % horizontal indent distance


\renewcommand{\syntleft}{}          % do not display '<' associated with variable, for example <A>
\renewcommand{\syntright}{}         % do not display '>' associated with variable, for example <A>

% Note: the empty line between production rules is not optional!

\begin{document}
    \begin{grammar}
        <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d

        <B> $\rightarrow$ B

        <C> $\rightarrow$ D 
    \end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

**Update** (`\phantom` solution)

```
\begin{grammar}\centering
        <S> $\ra$ abB 

        <A> $\ra$ aaBb

        <B> $\ra$ bbAa

        <A> $\ra$ $\lambda$
\end{grammar}
```

Comment: Do you care about the alignment of the production lines compared to one another? For example, that `<A>`, `<B>` and `<C>` should be below one another.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, I want to them to align with each other. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\centering` right after `\begin{grammar}` to center each production in its own line:

```
\begin{grammar}\centering
    <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d

    <B> $\rightarrow$ B \phantom{| c | d}

    <C> $\rightarrow$ D \phantom{| c | d}
\end{grammar}
```

Another approach; the `grammar` environment is defined as a list, so you could define a similar environment, to manually specify the `\leftmargin` length. In the following example I defined a `mygrammar` environment with an optional argument allowing you to control the `\leftmargin`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}  
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{syntax} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % to geberate text for the example 

\setlength{\grammarparsep}{0.25cm}   % vertical distance between production rules
\setlength{\grammarindent}{1cm}      % horizontal indent distance


\renewcommand{\syntleft}{}          % do not display '<' associated with variable, for example <A>
\renewcommand{\syntright}{}         % do not display '>' associated with variable, for example <A>

% Note: the empty line between production rules is not optional!

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mygrammar}[1][0pt]{%
\list{}{%
\labelwidth\grammarindent%
\leftmargin\dimexpr\grammarindent+#1\relax%
\advance\grammarindent\labelsep
\itemindent\z@%
\listparindent\z@%
\parsep\grammarparsep%
}%
\let\\\@normalcr
\syntaxShortcuts\relax\relax%
\def\alt{\\\llap{\textbar\quad}}%
\def\gr@setpar{%
\def\par{%
\parshape\@ne\@totalleftmargin\linewidth%
\@@par%
\catcode`\<12%
\everypar{%
\everypar{}%
\catcode`\<\active%
\gr@implitem%
}%
}%
}%
\gr@setpar%
\par%
\let\gr@leftsq\[%
\let\gr@rightsq\]%
\def\gr@endsyntdiag]{\end{syntdiag}\gr@setpar\par}%
\def\[{\@ifnextchar[{\begin{syntdiag}\@gobble}\gr@leftsq}%
\def\]{\@ifnextchar]\gr@endsyntdiag\gr@rightsq}%
}{%
\@newlistfalse%
\everypar{}%
\endlist%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}    

  <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d

   <B> $\rightarrow$ B

   <C> $\rightarrow$ D 
\end{grammar}

\begin{mygrammar}    

  <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d

   <B> $\rightarrow$ B

   <C> $\rightarrow$ D 
\end{mygrammar}

\begin{mygrammar}[3cm]    

  <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d

   <B> $\rightarrow$ B

   <C> $\rightarrow$ D 
\end{mygrammar}

\begin{mygrammar}[6cm]    

  <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d

   <B> $\rightarrow$ B

   <C> $\rightarrow$ D 
\end{mygrammar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another more automated approach: you simply provide the longest line as a mandatory argument for the newly defined `Cgrammar` environment, and you get the contents centered and with left alignment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}  
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{syntax} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % to geberate text for the example 

\setlength{\grammarparsep}{0.25cm}   % vertical distance between production rules
\setlength{\grammarindent}{1cm}      % horizontal indent distance


\renewcommand{\syntleft}{}          % do not display '<' associated with variable, for example <A>
\renewcommand{\syntright}{}         % do not display '>' associated with variable, for example <A>

% Note: the empty line between production rules is not optional!

\newlength\longest
\newlength\LeftMargin
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Cgrammar}[1]{%
\list{}{%
\settowidth\longest{#1}
\setlength\LeftMargin{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-0.5\longest}
\labelwidth\grammarindent%
\leftmargin\dimexpr\grammarindent+\LeftMargin\relax%
\advance\grammarindent\labelsep
\itemindent\z@%
\listparindent\z@%
\parsep\grammarparsep%
}%
\let\\\@normalcr
\syntaxShortcuts\relax\relax%
\def\alt{\\\llap{\textbar\quad}}%
\def\gr@setpar{%
\def\par{%
\parshape\@ne\@totalleftmargin\linewidth%
\@@par%
\catcode`\<12%
\everypar{%
\everypar{}%
\catcode`\<\active%
\gr@implitem%
}%
}%
}%
\gr@setpar%
\par%
\let\gr@leftsq\[%
\let\gr@rightsq\]%
\def\gr@endsyntdiag]{\end{syntdiag}\gr@setpar\par}%
\def\[{\@ifnextchar[{\begin{syntdiag}\@gobble}\gr@leftsq}%
\def\]{\@ifnextchar]\gr@endsyntdiag\gr@rightsq}%
}{%
\@newlistfalse%
\everypar{}%
\endlist%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}    

  <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d

   <B> $\rightarrow$ B

   <C> $\rightarrow$ D 
\end{grammar}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{Cgrammar}{A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d}

  <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d

   <B> $\rightarrow$ B

   <C> $\rightarrow$ D 
\end{Cgrammar}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{Cgrammar}{<A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d | e}

  <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d | e

   <B> $\rightarrow$ B

   <C> $\rightarrow$ D 
\end{Cgrammar}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{Cgrammar}{<A> $\ra$ aaBb}
        <S> $\ra$ abB 

        <A> $\ra$ aaBb

        <B> $\ra$ bbAa

        <A> $\ra$ $\lambda$
\end{Cgrammar}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, the variables A, B, and C don't align vertically with each other. Is there a work around?

Comment: @Chan: see my updated answer

Comment: Very nice solution ;) Many thanks for your effort. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Chan: see my third edit for an automated solution which only requires you to pass the longest line as an argument.

Comment: Melinda: Awesome. I bet I will learn many useful techniques from your solutions. Thank you Sir :)

Comment: @Chan: you're welcome. By the way, it's Medina and not Melinda ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\centering` as @Gonzalo suggested, and suppliment this with ample use of `\phantom{...}` to acquire the desired alignment:

```
\begin{grammar}\centering
    <A> $\rightarrow$ B | c | d

    <B> $\rightarrow$ B \phantom{| c | d}

    <C> $\rightarrow$ D \phantom{| c | d}
\end{grammar}
```

[image]

`\phantom{<stuff>}` makes a box of width of `<stuff>`, but does not typeset anything.

For your other example, one could use a predefined length of the largest item on the right-hand side (RHS) of your production. Then, using this length, you place each RHS in a box:

```
\newlength{\widest}% Length of widest element
\settowidth{\widest}{aaBb}% Widest element is "aaBb"
\newcommand{\rhs}[1]{\makebox[\widest][l]{#1}}
...
\begin{grammar}\centering
  <S> $\rightarrow$ \rhs{abB}

  <A> $\rightarrow$ \rhs{aaBb}

  <B> $\rightarrow$ \rhs{bbAa}

  <A> $\rightarrow$ \rhs{$\lambda$}
\end{grammar}
```

[image: Another centering method, this time using boxed to align BNF productions]

The [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) also offers a `\widthof{<stuff>}` command that you could use and remove the declaration of a new length like I did. However, the above illustrates the concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot the fix. I wonder will it work with a grammar of the form. See my update.

Comment: The graphic/image I've added shows that it does...

Comment: In your example, there is always a letter for every production. In my case, there is a single `\lambda` and other productions are string of letters. So I'm not sure exactly where should I group my `\phantom` section?

Comment: I the productions were just characters, liberal use of `\phantom` wherever you don't want something printed would work. However, introducing something like `\lambda`, which doesn't have a width that matches a regular character, requires a little more work. I've adapted my solution for such a case, placing the right-hand side elements in a box of fixed width, depending on the widest element you provide.